# How to animate a winforms custom control in C# without flickering?

Tags: c#, winforms, animation, custom-controls, accordion

I am looking for some help on how to animate a winforms custom control, the animations are simple fade-in fadeout or something a like an accordion style animation.

Can you please suggest any articles or code related to this.

Comment: You know that in WPF this would be easy?

Comment: I am not using WPF, Winforms please

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's called the DoubleBuffer property ([MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.doublebuffered)).

[Here's an example](https://web.archive.org/web/20140811193726/http://bobpowell.net/doublebuffer.aspx).

Comment: At least, you can achieve it with a DoubleBuffer

Answer (score 2):

Yep, use DoubleBuffer. A couple of [tips](http://timbar.blogspot.com/2007/05/double-buffering-in-c.html) I remember picking up:

- Don't do anything other than copy a back buffer to the control in the control's paint method.
- Handle refresh of the control in an independent thread.
- Don't call refresh from any event handlers that modify the control! :)